# Сортировка контента на лету

Tags: php, javascript, сортировка

Друзья. Помогите мне решить задачу сортировки контента на лету, чтобы можно было передвигать данные таблицы и их порядок менялся я пытался сделать, но почему-то не работает, код тут: http://jsfiddle.net/upxFk/

```
<table id="sort" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Код</td>
            <td>Название</td>
            <td>Цена</td>
            <td>Позиция</td>
            <td>Редактирование</td>
            <td>Удаление</td>
            <td>&#8659;&#8657;</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class=category>
                <td>0400</td><td>Специализированные ГИС</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&edit_cat=1>Редактировать</a></td>
                <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&delete_cat=1>Удалить</a></td>
                <td></td></tr>
<tr id=arrayorder_1>
                    <td id='id_1'>0101</td>
                    <td id='cat_1'>test test test  test test test</td>
                    <td>1500</td>
                     <td class='index_' id='1' abbr='1'>1</td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&edit_prod=1>Редактировать</a></td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&delete_prod=1>Удалить</a></td>
                    <td class='Drag' style='cursor:move'>&#8659;&#8657;</td></tr>
<tr id=arrayorder_15>
                    <td id='id_15'>0401</td>
                    <td id='cat_1'>ГИС "Оператор" для силовых структур (версия 11)</td>
                    <td>47000</td>
                     <td class='index_' id='15' abbr='7'>7</td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&edit_prod=15>Редактировать</a></td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&delete_prod=15>Удалить</a></td>
                    <td class='Drag' style='cursor:move'>&#8659;&#8657;</td></tr>
<tr id=arrayorder_14>
                    <td id='id_14'>123</td>
                    <td id='cat_1'>фывфывфыв</td>
                    <td>65535</td>
                     <td class='index_' id='14' abbr='3'>3</td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&edit_prod=14>Редактировать</a></td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&delete_prod=14>Удалить</a></td>
                    <td class='Drag' style='cursor:move'>&#8659;&#8657;</td></tr>
<tr class=category>
                <td>0100</td><td>Профессиональная ГИС</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&edit_cat=9>Редактировать</a></td>
                <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&delete_cat=9>Удалить</a></td>
                <td></td></tr>
<tr id=arrayorder_19>
                    <td id='id_19'>0101</td>
                    <td id='cat_9'>Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11)</td>
                    <td>59000</td>
                     <td class='index_' id='19' abbr='6'>6</td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&edit_prod=19>Редактировать</a></td>
                    <td><a class=control href=/gis/admin?act=products&delete_prod=19>Удалить</a></td>
                    <td class='Drag' style='cursor:move'>&#8659;&#8657;</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(window).load(function(){
                    $("td.Drag").mousemove(function(){$(this).css({cursor:"move"});});
                    var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
                    var $originals = tr.children();
                    var $helper = tr.clone();
                    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
                    $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
                     });
                    return $helper;
                    },
                     updateIndex = function(e, ui) {

                       $('td.index_', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
                       var ID=$(this).attr('id');
                       var POS=$(this).attr('abbr');
                       $(this).html(''+(i+1)+'');
                     });

                  var WW = new Array();var SS = new Array();var WW1="";var SS1="";var EE = [];var EE1 = "";
                     for(var S=1; S<=' . 4 . '; S++) {
                      SS[S-1] = $("td#"+S, ui.item.parent()).text() ;
                      WW[S-1]=$("td#id_"+S, ui.item.parent()).attr("class");
                      EE[S-1] = $("td#cat_"+S, ui.item.parent()).attr("class");
                      WW1 += WW[S-1] + ";";SS1 += SS[S-1] + ";";EE1 += EE[S-1] + ";";
                     }
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: "?act=savedragproduct",
             timeout: 5000,
             data: ({"id":WW,"pos":SS,"posid":EE1}),
             success: function(data){$("div#response").html(data);},
             error: function(data){$("div#response").html("Error");}
             });
             };
            $("#sort tbody").sortable ({
            helper: fixHelperModified,
            stop: updateIndex,
            cursor:"move",
            handle:".Drag"
            });
            });
</script>
```

Код самого php такой:

```
    $cat_pos = str_replace("undefined", "", $_POST['posid']);
    $cat_pos1 = str_replace(";", "", $cat_pos);
    $pos = str_replace("", "", $_POST['pos']);
    $id = str_replace("", "", $_POST['id']);
    $id1 = str_replace("undefined", "", $id);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `pos` = '$pos[$i]' WHERE `id` = '$id1[$i]' LIMIT 1;") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: Что делают:

    $pos = str_replace("", "", $_POST['pos']);
    $id = str_replace("", "", $_POST['id']);
?

Comment: да тут дело в том, что скрипт делает работу сортирует, но проблема в том он не отправляет новые позиции обработчику

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, расскажите какие данные вы пытаетесь отправить и проследите почему данные, во-первых, не формируются (с условием в цикле у вас проблема), во-вторых, что является у вас источником данных (у ваших td нет классов, а вы их пытаетесь получить).